# Advice in making a jQuery Data Table field clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mongodb

I've created a simple form. The form has a name field, a department field, and an employee number field. When the data is input and submitted, it is stored in MongoDB. On the page when the data is submitted, I've put a jQuery table below the form fields. When the data is submitted, you can see it tabularized by [_id],[Name],[Department], and [EmployeeNumber].

The "_id" field is randomly generated into the table from MongoDB.
My question: How do I make the "_id" field clickable. In that, when I click on it, it will open a small, pop-up browser window showing what is in the row, according to the "_id" field, and have a blank spot where a user can enter their name. The purpose of the user entering their name in this pop-up box/window is for tracking purposes, in that if user "John Smith" is currently "working" the specified "_id" then other users will know that he is working it when they click on that same "_id."

Thank you in advance for reading through, and any help you'll be able to give!

Comment: Your question is a little broad but since you are already using jquery you might want to look into the jqueryUI dialog: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Basically I'm wanting the "_id" field to be clickable. Once clicked, a dialogue box will pop up with a field for the user "working" that field to be able to add their name and a status, i.e., 'closed,' 'currently working,' etc.